# C# keyhook question

Tags: c#, keyhook

I copied the following code from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx,

```
public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam) 
{
    if (code >= 0) 
    {
     Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
     if (HookedKeys.Contains(key)) 
        {
         KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
         if((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null)) 
            {KeyDown(this, kea) ;} 
            else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null)) 
            {KeyUp(this, kea); }
            if (kea.Handled)
            {return 1;}
      }
     }
     lParam.vkCode ++;
     lParam.scanCode ++;
     return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
}
```

It works fine but when I make a little change:

```
lParam.vkCode ++;
or
lParam.scanCode ++;
```

right before the return CallNextHookEx(...), the original keys still appears in Notepad. 
Ex. If I press "a", I expect the letter in Notepad will be "b" but it still "a".
It seems like "lParam" doesn't change. Couldn't understand why?

Answer (score 1):

The value lParam.vkCode is not a simple int type so I don't think you can increment it in this fashion.

once you have your key object however ...

```
Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
```

You should be able to do something like get the byte value and increment that.

```
int keyVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetByte(key.KeyCode);
keyVal++;
```

I think vkCode is not the actual key code but maybe a pointer or something, by assigning it to the variable Key .Net pulls that value in and with your cast translates it to the managed key type.

Of course i could be wrong ...